Data Type Conversion error when setting FORMAT property in VBA
the code below creates tables based on settings in a table.
I'm trying to set the FORMAT property to "Standard" or "Percent" (meaning, i have tried both for different fields) and neither work, it errors on
    fld.Properties.Append db.CreateProperty("Format", vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldFormat)

with "Data Type Conversion Error"
field type is Double
Sub test()
    fnReports 4
End Sub

Function fnReports(vrReportNo As Long)

    Dim db As DAO.database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim vrSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vrTableName As String
    
    'create report table
     
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
 
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    vrTableName = "mtMDAR" & vrReportNo
    
    vrSQL = "SELECT MDARReportFields.SortNoField, MDARReportFields.FieldName, MDARReportFields.FieldSize, FieldFormats.FieldFormat " & _
            ", MDARReportFields.FieldDecimalNo, FieldDataTypes.FieldDataTypeNo, FieldDataTypes.FieldDataType, FieldDataTypes.FieldDataTypeVBA " & _
            "FROM FieldFormats RIGHT JOIN (FieldDataTypes RIGHT JOIN MDARReportFields ON FieldDataTypes.FieldDataTypeID = MDARReportFields.FieldDataTypeID) " & _
            "ON FieldFormats.FieldFormatID = MDARReportFields.FieldFormatID WHERE MDARReportFields.ReportNo=" & vrReportNo & "  ORDER BY MDARReportFields.SortNoField"
    
    fnDeleteObjectIfExists "table", vrTableName
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(vrTableName)
    
    Dim vrSortNoField As Long
    Dim vrFieldName As String
    Dim vrFieldSize As Long
    Dim vrFieldFormat As String
    Dim vrFieldDecimalNo As Long
    Dim vrFieldDataTypeNo As Long
    Dim vrFieldDataType As String
    Dim vrFieldDataTypeVBA As String
    Dim prp As DAO.Property
 
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsS = db.OpenRecordset(vrSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
   

    Do Until rsS.EOF
     
        vrFieldName = rsS!FieldName
        vrFieldDataTypeNo = rsS!FieldDataTypeNo

        With tdf
            Set fld = .CreateField(vrFieldName, vrFieldDataTypeNo)
            .Fields.Append fld
        End With
    

        rsS.MoveNext
    Loop
 
    db.TableDefs.Append tdf
    
    
    Set rsS = db.OpenRecordset(vrSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    Do Until rsS.EOF
    
        'vrSortNoField = rsS!SortNoField
        vrFieldName = rsS!FieldName
        vrFieldDataTypeVBA = rsS!FieldDataTypeVBA
        vrFieldDataTypeNo = rsS!FieldDataTypeNo
        vrFieldDataType = rsS!FieldDataType
        If vrFieldDataTypeVBA = "dbText" Then
            vrFieldSize = rsS!FieldSize
        Else
            vrFieldFormat = rsS!FieldFormat
            vrFieldDecimalNo = rsS!FieldDecimalNo
        
        End If
    
    
    

        With tdf
            Set fld = .Fields(vrFieldName)
         
            If vrFieldDataTypeVBA = "dbText" Then
                ' Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("FieldSize", vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldSize)
                '  fld.Properties.Append prp
            
                fld.Properties.Append db.CreateProperty("vrFieldFormat", vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldSize)
            Else
    
                Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DecimalPlaces", vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldDecimalNo)
                fld.Properties.Append prp
        
                If vrFieldFormat = "percent" Then
                    '                Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("Format", vrFieldDataTypeVBA, vrFieldFormat)
                    '                fld.Properties.Append prp
                    fld.Properties.Append db.CreateProperty("Format", vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldFormat)
                End If
            
            End If
  
        End With

        rsS.MoveNext
    Loop
 

    Set tdf = Nothing
    rsS.close
    Set rsS = Nothing
 
    Set db = Nothing
    
     
End Function


It's not clear why you need to create a table 'on the fly' and then set a format property on a field. It would appear that the tables have a fixed field layout so why not just create a template table and then copy it to whichever table name you need. Alternatively, create all required empty tables and just clear the data before loading fresh data. Both of these are far less complex than the path you have chosen.

theyre not fixed, each has a different set of fields. this is for a reporting module that will create and export reports on the fly, theyre all very different and this is my way of automating them. i have a bunch of tables which define fields, queries, and a ton more settings and then i can easily add reports, add fields, change criteris without having to redesign and add reports manually. i want to avoid releases of new versions for each report thats added, this is an easier way to do so. yes, initially complex but pays off later. ive done something similar before

however, i already solved this problem, just posted the answer, now i have one more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78704598/changing-decimalplaces-property-in-vba-from-auto

fixed, turns out for FORMAT property, the data type has to say dbText, no matter what the data type of the field is
fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, vrFieldFormat)

Right, in CreateProperty you define the data type of the property, which is separate from the data type of the field.  For example a Long Integer field has a Name property and that property will be text data type (just like all field names) even though the data type of the "named field" is numeric.

@HansUp omg lol, hi!!!))))) so happy to see that you're still around. huge thank you once more for all your help :) and thank you for this, now i understand how this works
