changing DecimalPlaces property in VBA from AUTO
I have a complex reporting module which creates reports on the fly, that's why I'm adding tables programmatically, this is a way to allow to add and edit reports without having to redesign the app.
Everything is dynamic, there's a set of tables that store configuration parameters and adding or changing a report just requires changing some data in those configuration tables.
So, need to change the DecimalPlaces property, it's set to Auto by default, I want to change it to 0 or 2 (depending on the settings).
The code doesn't give any errors but the property doesn't change, DecimalPlaces still says AUTO for all. I stepped through the code, it goes through those lines, just nothing changes in the table.
Sub test()
    fnReports 4
End Sub

Function fnReports(vrReportNo As Long)

    Dim db As DAO.database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim vrSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vrTableName As String
    
    'create report table
     
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
 
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    vrTableName = "mtMDAR" & vrReportNo
    
    vrSQL = "SELECT MDARReportFields.SortNoField, MDARReportFields.FieldName, MDARReportFields.FieldSize, FieldFormats.FieldFormat " & _
            ", MDARReportFields.FieldDecimalNo, FieldDataTypes.FieldDataTypeNo, FieldDataTypes.FieldDataType, FieldDataTypes.FieldDataTypeVBA " & _
            "FROM FieldFormats RIGHT JOIN (FieldDataTypes RIGHT JOIN MDARReportFields ON FieldDataTypes.FieldDataTypeID = MDARReportFields.FieldDataTypeID) " & _
            "ON FieldFormats.FieldFormatID = MDARReportFields.FieldFormatID WHERE MDARReportFields.ReportNo=" & vrReportNo & "  ORDER BY MDARReportFields.SortNoField"
    
    fnDeleteObjectIfExists "table", vrTableName
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(vrTableName)
    
    Dim vrSortNoField As Long
    Dim vrFieldName As String
    Dim vrFieldSize As Long
    Dim vrFieldFormat As String
    Dim vrFieldDecimalNo As Long
    Dim vrFieldDataTypeNo As Long
    Dim vrFieldDataType As String
    Dim vrFieldDataTypeVBA As String
    Dim prp As DAO.Property
 
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsS = db.OpenRecordset(vrSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
   

    Do Until rsS.EOF
     
        vrFieldName = rsS!FieldName
        vrFieldDataTypeNo = rsS!FieldDataTypeNo
        If vrFieldDataTypeNo = 10 Then
            vrFieldSize = rsS!FieldSize
        End If

        With tdf
            If vrFieldDataTypeNo = 10 Then
                Set fld = .CreateField(vrFieldName, vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldSize)
            Else
                Set fld = .CreateField(vrFieldName, vrFieldDataTypeNo)
            End If
            .Fields.Append fld
        End With

        rsS.MoveNext
    Loop
 
    db.TableDefs.Append tdf
    
    
    Set rsS = db.OpenRecordset(vrSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    Do Until rsS.EOF
    
        'vrSortNoField = rsS!SortNoField
        vrFieldName = rsS!FieldName
        vrFieldDataTypeVBA = rsS!FieldDataTypeVBA
        vrFieldDataTypeNo = rsS!FieldDataTypeNo
        vrFieldDataType = rsS!FieldDataType
        If vrFieldDataTypeNo <> 5 And vrFieldDataTypeNo <> 10 Then
            vrFieldFormat = rsS!FieldFormat
            vrFieldDecimalNo = rsS!FieldDecimalNo
        End If
    

        With tdf
            Set fld = .Fields(vrFieldName)
         
            If vrFieldDataTypeNo <> 5 And vrFieldDataTypeNo <> 10 Then
    
                Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DecimalPlaces", vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldDecimalNo)
                fld.Properties.Append prp
                 
         
                Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, vrFieldFormat)
                fld.Properties.Append prp
            
            End If
  
        End With

        rsS.MoveNext
    Loop
 

    Set tdf = Nothing
    rsS.close
    Set rsS = Nothing
 
    Set db = Nothing
    
     
End Function


What happens if you discard the CreateProperty and Properties.Append steps and try a simple direct assignment such as fld.Properties("DecimalPlaces").Value = 2

Instead of modifying table, could have code behind report in Detail_Format event modify textbox DecimalPlaces property. That's what I have done.

I tested @HansUp suggestion and it worked.

Normally, I use a function to test if a property exists, append if it doesn't, and set if it does. The solution by @HansUp will mostly work, as long as you're certain the property does exist in advance. The strange thing is this code should throw an error if the property exists, so something funky has to be going on with those comparisons.

@HansUp hey, tried this CreateProperty and Properties.Append steps and try a simple direct assignment such as fld.Properties("DecimalPlaces").Value = 2, no errors, just doesnt work, still says AUTO for all. stepped through the code, checked what happens right after that line - nothing.

@HansUp and yep, if it's set to AUTO, then it exists already

solved, all. same issue as before, DeimalPlaces must have dbByte as the data type, no matter what the field is. also, @HansUp, the property must be created for some reason, removing CreateProperty... gives an error that this property doesn't exist, weird

solved
turns out that the data type for DecimalPlaces is dbByte, not the property of a field
so, this
prp = fld.CreateProperty("DecimalPlaces", vrFieldDataTypeNo, vrFieldDecimalNo)

must be this
prp = fld.CreateProperty("DecimalPlaces", dbByte, vrFieldDecimalNo)

